# Scala polymorphism: data associated with a class

Tags: scala

I have a family of classes

```
class FooId extends Identifier {
  val prefix = "foo"
}
class BarId extends Identifier {
  val prefix = "bar"
}
```

where `prefix` is always a 'static' value. (Actually, at the moment, the value is repeated in the companion class.)

I would like to abstract over these to be able to easily serialize and deserialize any type of identifier. I would like to write a function like this:

```
val idFromString: PartialFunction[String, T <: Identifier] = {
  case s if s.startsWith(<T.prefix>) =>
      new T(Integer.parseInt(s.drop(<T.prefix>.length)))
}
```

but I don't know what should go in place of `<T.prefix>`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a method `def prefix : String` in your Identifier `Trait`

Thus, the method will be override by a val in subclass.

Comment: `T.prefix` still wouldn't work though. All _instances_ of `T` would have a `prefix` method, but I don't have an instance of `T`.